# Question suggestions

Tags: discussion, questions

Since we need to build up a collection of good questions it would be interesting to get some feedback as to what people perceive as being "expert" questions.

Whilst I'm not sure I'm an "expert" I do use EE a lot yet there are parts that make my brain hurt. The way categories work can drive me nuts sometimes and I'm sure there are areas that befuddle  even the best of us.

I think it would be good to make some question suggestions here - even things that we might feel are "easy" or "beginner" questions to get a feel as to whether or not they are in fact something that some of us struggle with. It might even be an idea to suggest topics that we can formulate some questions for.

I'll set the ball rolling by suggesting the topic of categories... so can anyone suggest some good category based questions?

Comment: Stash confuses me to know end and makes my brain wince in pain like you've just walked out of a dark cave after weeks alone. I know it's useful, but can't for the life of me "get" it.